# How to display cursorChar on auto write textview on android

Tags: java, xml, android-layout

**    I use implementation `com.dragankrstic.autotypetextview.AutoTypeTextView`
So I want to display cursorChar on the text write animation

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#E12B2B"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.dragankrstic.autotypetextview.AutoTypeTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        attv:typingPrecision="8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        attv:animateTextTypeWithoutMistakes="Hello Word"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
  
</RelativeLayout>
```

**

Comment: Please share more details about this problem.

Comment: I only need add cursor | for auto write animation on TextView like this please check this link ((https://ibb.co/BKcJYwD)